# req.session detiene json que se envia al frontEnd luego de haber asignado la session en node js con express

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs, express, express-session

estoy haciendo la autenticacion de usuario de un sistema con node js y express y tengo un problema al querer asignar un id a la sesión luego envió un json al frontend, pero este llega vació ya que al asignar el id a la sesión detiene la ejecucion del script, como puedo hacer para que al asignar un id de sesión  ademas pueda enviar el json al frontend. por ejemplo cuando un usuario no existe envía el json ya que no pasa por el asignar id, todo esto ademas es con una petición ajax

**app.js** (archivo principal node js)

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var http    = require("http");
var session    = require("express-session");
var RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);
var server  = http.Server(app);
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var session_middleware= require("./middlewares/session")


//=====================routers==============================
var router_usuario = require("./routers/usuario")
//=====================routers==============================
var sessionMiddleware=session(
 {
  store: new RedisStore({}),
  secret:"claveDesa",
  saveUninitialized:false
 }
);


app.set("view engine","jade")
app.use("/estatico",express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // peticiones para los que tienen formato 
application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(sessionMiddleware);

app.get("/",function(req,res){
 res.render("login")
 res.end();
})

app.get("app/inicio",function(req,res){
 res.render("home")
 res.end();
})

app.use("/app",session_middleware)
app.use("/login",router_usuario) // este router asigna el id a sesion
server.listen(8080);
```

**router usuario** (aca es donde se asigna el id a sesion y se envia json al frontend)

```
var express= require("express");
var usuario = require("../models/usuario")

var router=express.Router();
var obj= new usuario();
//router para autenticacion de usuario con su email y contraseña
router.post("/usuario/autenticacion",(req,res)=>{
     console.log(req.body)

   var array=[req.body.us_correo,req.body.us_clave];
   obj.inicioSesion(array).then(json=>{
      console.log( "el valor del json antes de enviar es " + JSON.stringify(json));

/*======== ESTE ES EL CONDICIONAL DONDE SE ASIGNA ID DEL USUARIO A SESION 
           Y SE DETIENE SCRIPT========*/
      if (json.sql.rows==1) {
           console.log("entro a json.sql.rows" + json.sql.rows)
           req.session.user_id=json.sql.data[0].us_id;
        //res.status(200).json({json});

       }
      console.log("me ejecuto luego de asignar la id de sesion")
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
      res.status(200).json({json});
      res.end();

  }).catch(json=>{
    res.status(200).json({json
    });

 })
});

module.exports=router;
```

**middleware sesion** (aca valido si sesion existe para acceder a paginas que lo requieran)

```
 var usuario = require("../models/usuario");
 module.exports=(req,res,next)=>{
     console.log("el valor de req session es " + req.session.user_id)
 if(!req.session.user_id){
     console.log("entro en if !req.session.user_id")
     res.redirect("/");
  }
 else{
    console.log("entro en else !req.session.user_id")
    var objUsuario = new usuario();
    objUsuario.validarSesion([req.session.user_id]).then((json)=>{

  if (json.sql.rows==1) { // guardar datos de usuarios en session
      var data     = json.sql.data[0];
      var usuario = {us_nombres:data.us_nombres,us_apellidos:data.us_apellidos,us_correo:data.us_correo}
      res.locals={usuario:usuario}
      next();
  }
}).catch((json)=>{
       console.log("error al validar la session")
       console.log(json);
       res.redirect("/");
})
 }
}
```

intente enviando el json primero y luego asignado el id a la sesion pero sale otro error **Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client**

Comment: El controlador tendría que responder con un res.send(json); Creo que con el res.end() no consigues ese efecto.

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia intente lo que mencionas pero sigue igual

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia intente tambien hacerlo con submit y un redirect pero queda en un loop infinito.

Comment: ¿Podrías postear el código de `/models/usuario` para ver bien el método `inicioSesion()`?. Otra cosa, en tu "CONDICIONAL DONDE SE ASIGNA ID DEL USUARIO A SESION" me parece que no está bien planteada la condición. Por eso quisiera ver el método que te pido, para poder orientarte un poco. Hay bastantes detalles en la forma en la que planteas tu código y me gustaría ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras era el metodo inicioSesion ya que no traia los datos del usuario por tanto al querer acceder al atributo us_id era undefined , los mas raro fue que no mostro el error al principio.

Comment: @MauricioContreras que puedo hacer con esta pregunta la cierro ya que fue un error de logica mia.

Comment: Puedes publicar tu propia respuesta y luego la aceptas como válida. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución es que no obtenía los datos del usuario que era un parámetro que estaba en false y debía estar en true, por consiguiente al capturar el id de usuario obtenía undefined(no mostraba el error al principio) y  por eso entregaba un json vació.

dentro de este metodo que muestro a continuacion hago una llamada a otro metodo(super.transaccionParametrizada) el cual tiene un parametro boolean para mostrar o no los datos.

```
inicioSesion(array){
 console.log("entro en inicio sesion")
console.log(array)
var sql="SELECT *, count(us_id) as existe FROM app_coffice.usuario where us_correo=$1 and app_coffice.crypt($2,us_clave)=us_clave group by us_id ";
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    console.log("entro a promesa en inicio de sesion")
  //  super.transaccionParametrizada(sql,array)
    super.transaccionParametrizada(sql,array,true).then(json=>{
        console.log("el valor de massive parametros es " + json)
       resolve(json);
    }). catch(json=>{
        console.log("entramos en catch ")
        console.log(json);
       reject(json)
    });
})
}
```